# Spring Data Rest Put not updating with immutable entity on SpringBoot 2.1.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-rest

After updating to the spring boot starter version 2.1.5 put requests don't update the entity anymore with immutable entities.

Put requests work on spring boot starter 2.0.3 but not on 2.1.4 & 2.1.5. Using the Patch method however works fine.

Since I am working in Kotlin my code is written in Kotlin but I can also reproduce this with a Java entity:

Given the entites:

```
@Entity
data class MyEntityKt(
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     val id: UUID? = null,
     @Version
     val version: Long = 0,
     val name: String = "",
     val description: String = ""
)
```

```java
@Value
@Wither
@Entity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyEntityJava {

    public MyEntityJava() {
        id = null;
        version = 0;
        name = "";
        description = "";
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private final UUID id;
    @Version
    private final long version;
    private final String name;
    private final String description;
}
```

And the two corresponding RestRepositories:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "kotlin")
interface MyEntityRepository : JpaRepository<MyEntityKt, UUID>

@RepositoryRestResource(path = "java")
interface ImmutableEntityRepository : JpaRepository<MyEntityJava, UUID>
```

And in my test (`@SpringBootTest`) I try the following:

```
@Test
fun testPut() {
    val myEntity = myEntityRepository.save(MyEntityKt(name = "TestName", description = "TestDescription"))
    val update = this.mockMvc.perform(
        put("/kotlin/${myEntity.id}")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(
                """
                {
                    "name": "TestNameModified",
                    "description": "TestDescriptionModified"
                }
            """.trimIndent()
            )
    )
    .andReturn().response.contentAsByteArray.let { objectMapper.readValue(it, MyEntityKt::class.java) }

    val updatedEntity = myEntityRepository.findById(myEntity.id!!).get()

    assertThat(updatedEntity.name).isEqualTo("TestNameModified")    
    assertThat(updatedEntity.description).isEqualTo("TestDescriptionModified")
}
```

Also the response I get is:

```
{
    "name" : "TestName",
    "description" : "TestDescription",
    "_links" : {
    "self" : {
        "href" : "http://localhost/kotlin/fd83f256-3515-41b0-b9c7-7bfe53a367f8"
    },
    "myEntityKt" : {
        "href" : "http://localhost/kotlin/fd83f256-3515-41b0-b9c7-7bfe53a367f8"
    }
}
```

I did some investigation and `org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.DomainObjectReader.MergingPropertyHandler#doWithPersistentProperty` which I guess would be responsible for creating an updated version of my entity to persist, seems like it is only setting the values on the accessor but not actually creating an updated object.

On spring boot version 2.0.3 the test case passes, on 2.1.5 however the entity is not updated, and there is no actual reason given (eg, log output) why the entity is not updated. My guess is that it has something to do with the fact that the entites are immutable but I don`t see why this worked previously.

EDIT: I uploaded the testcase to [Github](https://github.com/Tree4Free/SpringDataRestProblemTestCase)

Comment: Because you get the same entity from the first level cache and not a fresh one. Inject the `EntityManager` before doing the `findById` call `clear` on the `EntityManager` and then do the `findById` to force the reloading from the db. Also your entities aren't immutable from the JPA sense, using reflection you could still change them. Your JPA provider might have some extensions, like hibernate has the `@Immutable` annotation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this does not resolve the problem, I edited the question and as you can now see the json response I get back also shows the old state of the entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem:

1. Annotate the entity as Immutable
2. Make the version and the id property mutable

```
@Entity
@org.springframework.data.annotation.Immutable
data class MyEntityKt(
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     var id: UUID? = null,
     @Version
     var version: Long = 0,
     val name: String = "",
     val description: String = ""
)
```

The Immutable annotation caused the json response that I was getting to be the correctly updated one but it inserted a new entry into the database with my updated values.

So to make it override the existing entity I had to make the id and the version mutable.

Also in the json I send to update the entity I included the version to work for subsequent updates like this:

```
{
    "name": "TestNameModified",
    "description": "TestDescriptionModified",
    "version": 0
}
```

Comment: Why is ID mutable ? You shouldn't change database ID ever it's bad practice. If so then you should delete current entity and create new. Database sequence should generate new ID...

Comment: @Martin Čuka It seemed like Spring was not setting the ID on the updated entity during the merge of the old entity and the updated one when it was immutable, which resulted in a new database entry.